# How to set log4j in my javafx application?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Recently I created a **javafx 2.2** application. As ran the application (native bundle created using Wix and Inno5 )outside my **Netbeans(JDK 7u40 with NetBeans 7.3.1)** shows a popup error "**Exception while Running Application** " The jar file in dist folder works fine.

Image link of error:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDWly.jpg

Somewhere i've seen somebody solved the same problem by configuring the logger. Since i have never did it before i need some help.

-Thanks

Comment: ...and you're not getting an exception stack anywhere?  Not even in the output tab at the bottom of Netbeans?  I'd say, let's start there before we worry about wiring in logging.

Comment: im not getting any exception in the output. only when running the app outside netbeans (native bundle)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See the documentation of apache log4j. that gives a good explanation

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html